# Как при помощи javascript обработать информацию приходящую из java?

Tags: javascript, java

Здравствуйте, в результате работы rest-контроллера:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/department")
public class DepartmentRestController {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentService departmentService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/byId/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public DepartmentDto getDepartmentById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return departmentService.getDepartmentById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/byParent/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public List<DepartmentDto> getDepartmentsByParent(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return departmentService.getDepartmentsByParent(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/byName/{filter}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public List<DictionaryItem> getDepartmentsByName(@PathVariable String filter) {
        return departmentService.getDepartmentsByName(filter);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/fullTree", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public DepartmentDto getDepartmentsFullTree() {
        return departmentService.getDepartmentsFullTree();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    public DepartmentDto createDepartment(@RequestBody DepartmentDto entity) {
        return departmentService.createDepartment(entity);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updateDepartment(@RequestBody DepartmentDto entity) {
        departmentService.updateDepartment(entity);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/byId/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteDepartmentsByIds(@PathVariable Long id) {
        departmentService.deleteDepartment(id);
    }
}
```

Получается вот такая информация:

```
{"id":1,
"login":"ivanenko.ivanovich",
"password":"example",
"role":null,
"lastName":"Иваненко",
"firstName":"Иван",
"middleName":"Иванович",
"department":null,
"email":null,
"phone":"0954533452",
"description":"Хороший студент",
"testResults":null}
```

Как пользоваться этой информацией в java? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `Как при помощи javascript обработать` .....`Как пользоваться этой информацией в java?`....... так где конкретно вы хотите что-то с этим делать?

Comment: Я хочу из полученной информации от java сделать объект javascript

Comment: @user212179 как я вижу, Вы получаете JSON от сервера.Самый простой вариант - это применить функцию JSON.parse() - которая вернет вам объект на основе переданной JSON строки.

Comment: @enzo, оформите, пожалуйста, свой комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы отправляете запрос серверу, используя какую-либо JS библиотеку (как обычно и бывает), например, JQuery, то вообще ничего **парсить не нужно**. Тип ответа определяется самой функцией или параметром запроса. Что это означает? В качестве примера, посмотрите на описание функции JQuery
[`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). В документации сказано:

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Т.е. просто сокращение для стандартной функции выполения AJAX запроса с предопределенным значением параметра `dataType`. Таким образом, вы сразу говорите, что сервер возвращает данные в формате JSON. Ваша JS библиотека, зная об этом, автоматически распарсит JSON и предоставит готовый JS объект.

> **The success callback is passed the returned data**, which is typically a
>   JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure **and parsed**
>   **using the $.parseJSON() method**.

Т.е. на выходе запроса в success callback у вас должен быть готовый JS объект.
Простейший пример запроса:

**JQuery**

*HTML*

```
<span id="login"></span>
```

*JS*

```
$.getJSON( "/api/department/byId/1", function(data) {
    console.log(data.login);
    $('#login').text(data.login);
});
```

**Angular**

*HTML*

```
<span>{{department.login}}</span>
```

*JS*

```
$http.get("/api/department/byId/1").then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    $scope.department = response.data;
});
```

Ваш контроллер можно, в принципе, убрать из вопроса - для ответа более значимым является код клиента